# How to display comment form submit without refresh the page using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Comment Form is submitting and also data getting saved to the database. But not displaying on the browser without refreshing the page.

here is the code:

```
$("#post_reply").click(function (event) {
    $("#data_status").html("");
    $('#ajax_loading').show();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (document.getElementById('_comment').value.trim() == "") {
        return false;
    }
    $.post('../services/leave_comment.php', $("#open_status").serialize(), function (data) {
        $('#ajax_loading').hide();
        if (data.split("::")[1] == true) {
            $("#data_status").html("Commented Successfully..");
            $("#data_status").fadeOut(3000);
            document.getElementById('_comment').value = '';
            $('#_comment').html("");

        } else if (data.split("::")[1] == false) {
            $("#data_status").html("Error occured in Comment Submission.. TryAgain..");
            $("#data_status").fadeOut(3000);
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

All i can understand is i haven't published the data with ajax?? 
Is this what i need to do??

```
$("#post_reply").click(function (event) {
$("#data_status").html("");
$('#ajax_loading').show();
event.preventDefault();
if (document.getElementById('_comment').value.trim() == "") {
    return false;
}
$.post('../services/leave_comment.php', $("#open_status").serialize(), function (data) {
    $('#ajax_loading').hide();
    if (data.split("::")[1] == true) {
        $("#data_status").html("Commented Successfully..");
        $("#data_status").fadeOut(3000);
        document.getElementById('_comment').value = '';
        $('#_comment').html("");


$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url : 'http://localhost/tech1/services/get_more_comments.php',  
data: 'last_id='+last_id,
success: function(data){
$('.view_container').append(data);
},
complete: function(){
console.log('DONE');
                    }                       
                });

    } else if (data.split("::")[1] == false) {
        $("#data_status").html("Error occured in Comment Submission.. TryAgain..");
        $("#data_status").fadeOut(3000);
    }
});
 });
```

Comment: what is not displayed?

Comment: @GertB. comment is not displayed. It happens me to refresh the page to view the comment.

Comment: i don't see in your code where you add the comment to your page

Comment: you php code does not change till you refresh the page, you can add the comment using jquery or javascript

Comment: I dint understand what your saying, am new to this scripting can u please elaborate.

Comment: well your php loads the comments from the database as it loads the page, and shows the results. you add a comment using ajax, that will be displayes in the database. PHP does not reload when you do a ajax call, so the page does not change.

Comment: in your javascript code on the other hand, you can add elements to the page without reloading

Answer (score 0):

All your code does is post the data to the server. There is nothing that fetches the new comments from the server or manually appends the posted comment. You can either use ajax again to refresh comments or more simply append a comment with the posted content.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to search the web for jQuery's `.load` :

example:

```
function updateShouts(){
   // Assuming we have #shoutbox
   $('#shoutbox').load('latestShouts.php');
}
```

in this case `shoutbox` would be the containing div with your comments,
you would call this function on the success of your ajax post
latestshouts.php would only contain the content of that div.

kinda hard to explain, i hope it makes sense to you

link: http://api.jquery.com/load/